# Why is System.out.getClass() called for each println reference?

Tags: java, compilation, decompiling

My source is written like this:

```
final Collection<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("apple");
list.add("banana");
list.add("orange");
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

After compiled and decompiled, I found this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("apple");
list.add("banana");
list.add("orange");
PrintStream var10001 = System.out;
System.out.getClass();
list.forEach(var10001::println);
```

OK, System.out has to be initialized, I get that. However, my very next two lines of source are:

```
final Random r = new Random();
r.ints(7, 14).limit(5).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

The decompiled class gave me this:

```
Random r = new Random();
IntStream var10000 = r.ints(7, 14).limit(5L).sorted();
var10001 = System.out;
System.out.getClass();
var10000.forEach(var10001::println);
```

This seems like a safety overkill. Is there an actual reason for the compiler to do the second getClass() call?

Comment: I guess I'm not familiar with the `::` operator, I was under the impression that lambda syntax was `list.forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));`

Comment: IIRC, the compiler sometimes inserts that as a super-trivial null check.

Comment: @Powerlord, the `::` is part of a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), which is a special form of lambda.